# iOS Admob Interstitial Ad Freezes and becomes non responsive

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, admob, gadinterstitial

I have implemented Admob Interstitial Ad, and it works fine on all devices like documented in the following link [Google Mobile Ads SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/interstitial). The issue is when testing on iPhone X only, the Ad becomes non responsive and not clickable when the ad contains a playable video inside it. Anyone has encountered such weird behavior? The SDK Version is 7.33.1.

Check the screenshot below:

[image: Ad Interstitial Non Responsive]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was an issue in Google Admob SDK, I updated to the recent released version 7.34 and it worked fine!

Comment: I have a same issue with recent version of Google Admob SDK. Any other solutions?

Comment: My current sdk version is 7.42.2

Comment: I did a work around and added a timer of 0.8 seconds before displaying the ad. Try this and let me know if it works

Comment: I added a timer like you said. It seems to work. I will comment later if it really works when published. Thanks!

Comment: I resolved this issue adding a timer of 0.8 second as Ali Zahr mentioned. Thanks @Ali Zahr